# Increment build number using plist variable with Fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, fastlane

I want **fastlane** to use the variable named `CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION` that I put under `Bundle version` of my plist. Right now, it increment the bundle version and hardcode the value on all my target instead of just incrementing that single variable.

Problem is, if I want someday to increment it manually, I have to change it by hand on all my target since **fastlane** break the link with my variable on every build.

Here is my current **fastlane** setup:

```
  lane :bumpVersion do
    increment_build_number
    commit_version_bump
  end
```

Comment: Check out the versioning plugin https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning and their readme on how latest Xcode manages versioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```rb
def infoPlistPath
    rootDir = File.expand_path("..", Dir.pwd)
    infoPlistPath = "#{rootDir}/Project/Target/Info.plist"
    return infoPlistPath
end

def currentProjectVersion
    version = get_info_plist_value(path: infoPlistPath, key: "CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION")
    return version
end

lane :bumpVersion do
    increment_build_number(
      build_number: currentProjectVersion,
    )
end
```